# Which is faster, creating processes or Threads? And why?

Tags: process, java-threads

I just wanna understand which is faster , the thread or the process and why is that  ? 
all the information i get is about the difference of weight

Answer (score 0):

In the overwhelming majority of cases we can assume that the  process creating takes much more time than creating a new thread in an existing process. Creating a process requires at least:

1. Classes loading and verification.[*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)
2. Linking. [*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3)
3. Classes initialization. [*](https://www.developer.com/java/data/understand-jvm-loading-jvm-linking-and-jvm-initialization.html)
4. Static members initialization. [*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)

Follow the link, there you will find a lot of detailed information about the process loading and you will understand that this is a very cumbersome procedure.

А new thread creating as a whole requires only operation system call.